Drawing graphs to visualize Hopcroft-Karp
I am trying to draw graphs similar to the second picture. Using tikz-graphs I was able to draw simple bipartite graphs, but I couldn't get the following things to work:

I draw bipartite graphs using the subgraph I_nm command. But the left and right sides of the graph are drawn at the same height, even though they don't have the same number of nodes. I would prefer it to look like the left graph in the picture below.
I was not able to color some nodes in the graph in a different color (the graph in the picture has yellow and blue nodes).
I tried to draw the right graph with layered layout, but the order I want is ignored. The problem is probably the internal algorithm that tries to minimize crossings.

Here is the code:
\begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \graph[nodes={draw, circle, fill=blue}, radius=.5cm, empty nodes, branch down=1 cm, grow right sep=4cm] {
                subgraph I_nm [V={l_1, l_2, l_3, l_4, l_5, l_6, l_7}, W={r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5, r_6, r_7, r_8}];
                l_1 -- r_2;
                l_1 -- r_3;
                l_2 -- r_1;
                l_2 -- r_2;
                l_3 -- r_1;
                l_3 -- r_3;
                l_3 -- r_4;
                l_3 -- r_5;
                l_3 -- r_6;
                l_4 -- r_2;
                l_4 -- r_3;
                l_4 -- r_7;
                l_5 -- r_4;
                l_5 -- r_5;
                l_5 -- r_6;
                l_5 -- r_7;
                l_6 -- r_3;
                l_6 -- r_7;
                l_7 -- r_5;
                l_7 -- r_8
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \graph [layered layout, nodes={draw, circle}, grow=right] {

                { [same layer] 1, 2, 3};
                { [same layer] a, b, c};
                { [same layer] 4, 5, 6};
                { [same layer] d, e, f, g};

                1 -> {a, b};
                2 -> {a, b, c};
                3 -> {b, c};
                a -> 4;
                b -> 5;
                c -> 6;
                4 -> d;
                5 -> {d, e, f, g};
                6 -> {e, f, g};
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}

If possible, I want to avoid using explicit coordinates and continue to rely on TikZ's graph drawing algorithms.



Welcome to tex.sx.

Are you able to edit your code so it can be compiled? Please note the one question-per question format. I'm a bit confused: these both look like cases where you want a very specific layout with the nodes precisely ordered. So what exactly do you want from the layout algorithms?

Welcome.
Not sure to which extent you read and digested chapter "IV Graph Drawing" in the pgfmanual. If you skim through it, and have some basic experience with previous parts, like using \node, the repeating syntax pattern should become evident at some point in time.
This modification of your upper attempt:

allows you to set node-options with the "nodes" you place
lets me puzzled with why you use subgraph I_nm here at all (it's no declaration of nodes or so)
trying to modify "node" options there didn't work, probably because your code seems to be syntactically

From the manual, two steps:

define a V x W matrix (subgraph statement with ;)
draw the intended interconnections manually
if you don't like that, a \foreach loop should do the job (but probably doesn't simplify code overall)


Because the examples you show have so many exceptions, i.e. irregular connections, I doubt you can delegate that to a large extent to subgraph or similar statements. One way or the other you'll have to tell how things should be (different) here).
Alternatives for placing nodes first may be:

using tikzlibrary positioning
or better \matrix (see ch. "5.3 Aligning the Nodes Using Matrices")
\foreach loops
and several more


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,graphdrawing} \usegdlibrary {trees}

\begin{document}
             \begin{tikzpicture}
                \graph[nodes={draw, circle, fill=blue}, radius=.5cm, empty nodes, branch down=1 cm, grow right sep=4cm] {
%                subgraph I_nm [V={l_1[fill=yellow], l_2, l_3, l_4, l_5, l_6, l_7}, W={r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5, r_6, r_7[red], r_8}];
                l_1[red] -- r_2;
                l_1 -- r_3[fill=yellow];
                l_2 -- r_1;
%                l_2 -- r_2;
%                l_3 -- r_1;
%                l_3 -- r_3;
%                l_3 -- r_4;
%                l_3 -- r_5;
%                l_3 -- r_6;
%                l_4 -- r_2;
%                l_4 -- r_3;
%                l_4 -- r_7;
%                l_5 -- r_4;
%                l_5 -- r_5;
%                l_5 -- r_6;
%                l_5 -- r_7;
%                l_6 -- r_3;
%                l_6 -- r_7;
%                l_7 -- r_5;
%                l_7 -- r_8
                };
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

